# replace text using regular Expression in Notepad++

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I have following text as input.

```
1 "India"  1 "IN" 
2 "Germany" 2 "GM" 
3 "Canada"  3 "CN" 
4 "United States"  4 "US"
```

and I want to convert all this strings to following pattern

```
<value in="India" out="IN"/> 
<value in="Germany" out="GM"/> 
<value in="Canada" out="CN"/> 
<value in="United States" out="US"/>
```

How to do it using regular expression?
I am using notepad++

Comment: This is a simple task for regular expressions. Show what you have already tried and explain why it does not do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find : `^.*?"([^"]+)"[^"]+"(\w+)"`

replace with : `<value in="\1" out="\2"/>`

output :

```
<value in="India" out="IN"/> 
<value in="Germany" out="GM"/> 
<value in="Canada" out="CN"/> 
<value in="United States" out="US"/>
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/hH3rZ4

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you place the cursor at the beginning of the file.

1. Hit `CTRL+H`.
2. Choose the `Replace` tab.
3. Select `Regular Expression` at the bottom.

   ```
   Find: \d+\s+"(.*?)".*?"(.*?)"  
   Replace: <value in="\1" out="\2"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Notepad++, but in SubEthaEdit, I would do this:

Find:

```
[^"]*("[^"]*")[^"]*("[^"]*")[^"]*
```

(five sections of "not a quote", separated by quotes, capturing the two quoted parts)

Replace:

```
<value in=\1 out=\2/>\n
```

This ought to be very similar in Notepad++.